# How to delete ''image 1/15'' but keep title in FancyBox Gallery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, fancybox

I am using FancyBox gallery in the WP Village theme.

At the moment, I have `title` and `image 1/15`...
I need to keep the `title` and delete "`image 1/15`"... 
Any idea????

Some help would be greatly appreciated !!!!

Thanks in advance

Zephyr

Comment: can you identify the script where fancybox is initialized? ... something like `$(".selector").fancybox({ // options })` ? ... does your theme an option to customize the modal box?

Comment: Posting a link to the site, or some code would be useful.

Comment: It gets added like this: <span id="fancybox-title-over">Image 1 / 3 Custom title</span> He wants to remove the "Image 1 / 3" and keep the rest...

Comment: Can you not just remove the "rel" element from the images? That's what groups them together and gives you your image numbers

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found the solution, it was a bit tricky, in the php. file and not in the js. Someone did it for me, so I can't tell you more about it...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.. simply delete in comment line code for hide image 1 of 1...

```
afterLoad : function() {
    //this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');

    // **Solutions**

    this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
}
```